# onload not calling my JS function?

Tags: php, html, ajax

i added this JS code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    var mTimer;
    var url = "www-rainbowcode-net/apps_dev.php/messagebox/list";

    function getXmlHttpRequestObject()
    {
        alert("in gethttprequest");
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        else 
        {
            //document.getElementById('p_status').innerHTML = 'Status: Cound not create XmlHttpRequest Object.';
        }
    } 

    function getNewMessage()
    {
        if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) 
        {        
            alert("state is" + receiveReq.readyState);
            //var params = "name" + name + "&" + "comment=" + comment;
            receiveReq.open("POST", url, true);
            receiveReq.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
            receiveReq.send(null);
        }
    }

    function processReqChange()
    {
        // only if req shows "loaded"
        if (receiveReq.status == 200) 
        {
            alert("processed" + receiveReq.responseText);
           document.getElementById("message_area").innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the XML data:\n" +
            receiveReq.statusText);
        }
        mTimer = setTimeout('getNewMessage();',2000);
    }        
</script>
```

then i have my html mixed with php:

```
<body onload = "return getNewMessage();">
   <table width='96%' border='0'>
       <?php 
        $cursor = $pager->getFirstIndice(); 
        foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg)
        { 
            $has_freechat = false;  
            //changed id to withid here
        $freechat_req_link="profiles/confirmfreechat?withid=".$msg->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdFrom()->getId();                                               
$freechat_req_link=link_to('Freechat',$freechat_req_link,'class=link_small_dark');

        $cc = sizeof ($fc_records);
        for($i = 0; $i < $cc; $i++) 
        {
    if($fc_records[$i]->getProfileIdWith() == $msg->getProfileIdFrom())
    {       
        $has_freechat = true;       
        break;
    }
      } 
      $unique_code_from = $msg->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdFrom()->getUniqueCode();
      $block_url = link_to('Block User',"blocklist/block?unqiue_code=$unique_code_from",'class=link_medium_blue');
          echo "<div id = 'message_area'>";
      echo "<tr>";
          $date = add_date($msg->getCreatedAt(),$hr=2);
      echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".$date."</td>";
          $opened_once = $msg->getOpenedOnce();
          if($opened_once >= 1)
          {
              echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".link_to($msg->getSubject(),   'messagebox/read?cursor='.$cursor,'class=link_medium_blue')."</td>";
          }    
          else
          { ?>
          <td align='left'>
             <a href="<?php echo url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor ?>" style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'><?php echo $msg->getSubject();?>             </a>        
          </td>      
          <?php 
       } 
 echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".$unique_code_from." ( $block_url )</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</div>";
   ++$cursor; 
 }
 </table>
```

can anybody tell me why my alerts in the 2nd and 3rd function dont execute? the one in the 1st executes

thanks

Comment: removed it and added line mkk suggested but no difference ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in getNewMessage you miss () for processReqChange

update:

```
  function getNewMessage()
{
    if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) 
    {        
        alert("state is" + receiveReq.readyState);
        //var params = "name" + name + "&" + "comment=" + comment;
        receiveReq.open("POST", url, true);
        receiveReq.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        receiveReq.send(null);
    }
     mTimer = setTimeout("getNewMessage()", 5000);
}
```

Comment: window.onload? but the page must refresh say every 2000secs because new messages can come constantly when two people are "chatting" on the website.. while i am on the page new message must show as thew arrive/
i moved/added your line but still not doing the other two alerts?

Comment: @Helloise you are missing () in processReqChange(). I updated my answer

Comment: i call this now: 

setTimeout(function()
        {
           window.location.reload(1);
        }, 5000);

but now the page flickers every 5 sec! dont want that..any other way please help? thanks alot

Comment: @Helloise your previous code was ok! i think what was causing the error was bad sytnax! in 5th line in getNewMessage you have receiveReq.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; instead of receiveReq.onreadystatechange = processReqChange(); <- you forgot () to invoke your method

Comment: thanks! i added the () only thing now is to get the page NOT to flicker every 5000??? is there another way other than setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(1); }, 5000); ??

thanks!

Comment: @Helloise window.location refreshes your page! you do not want to use it! setTimeout("getNewMessage()",5000) should work but put it in the getNewMessage ! see my updated answer

Comment: @mkk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2653/discussion-between-helloise-smit-and-mkk)